# finding the @ character in a string

Tags: php

If I wanted to find the  @ character within a string. Would I use preg_match?

This is what I am trying now.

```
if (preg_match('/^@/', $email)===TRUE) {
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you use `^`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression isn't necessary. You can use `strpos`.

```
if (strpos($email, "@") !== FALSE)
    //...
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginnning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns **FALSE** if the needle was not found.

Answer (score 2):

Since your search is so simple, I'd recommend using [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

```
// stripos returns false if not found
$found = (stripos($str, "@")) !== false);
```

Comment: Case-insensitive match on an @ symbol? :-P

Answer (score 2):

preg_match is a bit overkill if you are just trying to find the @ symbol.  Using strpos would be more appropriate, especially since you aren't really doing any regular expression matching.